# 'Transaction cannot be rolled back...' using unmanaged transactions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

We use unmanaged transactions in many cases but this issue only occurs in 2 functions which are invoked more commonly and only on production environment (Haven't been able to reproduce it on dev).

Our code looks similar to this:

```
const t = await database.t();
try {
 await function1(..., {t});
 await function2(..., {t});
}
catch (e) {
await t.rollback();  <- This throws the error
throw e 
};
// more logic
await t.commit();
```

Where database is just a Sequelize instantiation with name of database, username and password.
We assumed it's a connection error according to this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4850 but in this case code wouldn't reach beyond line one on our pseudocode.

Error output on CloudWatch:
[image]

Comment: Why dont you commit inside the try block?

Comment: @AbhishekShah We have 3 or 4 try/catches in the same function. Everything needs to succeed in order to commit.

Comment: So you should not rollback in every catch block. Are you? If yes you need to check if transaction has been rollback/commit before doing further rollback/commit as it will then throw error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple try-catch then maybe need to check the transaction state before rollback/commit:

```js
const t = await database.t();
try {
    await function1(..., { t });
    await function2(..., { t });
}
catch (e) {
    if (!t.finished) {
        await t.rollback();
    }
    throw e;
};
// more logic
await t.commit();
```

Reference links:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6547#issuecomment-466016971
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/5043/files#diff-6c5ddfc7d68c447e32ef4c38b7ed69628910355ea0aff735bd4bcecc1256a8d8

Comment: I only rollback at one specific catch and one only. It turns out the problem is not from application logic but instead an unhandled connection error from Sequelize which automatically rollbacks the state for some reason.